# Is there an accepted name for a fake object injected via a preprocessor seam?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, terminology, naming

I am dealing with some old, sloppy C++ code in which there is a structure with a lot of data members and functions. I want to test a class that I have implemented which uses the struct, but this dependency is going to make the unit tests extremely ugly. Inspired by Michael Feather's discussion of **preprocessing seams** in *Working Effectively with Legacy Code*, I am getting ready to solve this problem by faking the ugly structure with the preprocessor (not with inheritance) polymorphism as demonstrated in the following notional code.

#### test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NotAsUgly.hpp"
#include "DependsOnUgly.hpp"
int main() {
    std::cout << DependsOnUgly().getDescription() << std::endl;
}
```

#### DependsOnUgly.hpp

```
#ifndef _DEPENDS_ON_UGLY_HPP_
#define _DEPENDS_ON_UGLY_HPP_
#include <string>
#include "Ugly.hpp"
class DependsOnUgly {
public:
    std::string getDescription() {
        return "Depends on " + Ugly().getName();
    }
};
#endif
```

#### Ugly.hpp

```
#ifndef _UGLY_HPP_
#define _UGLY_HPP_
struct Ugly {
    double a, b, ..., z;
    void extraneousFunction { ... }
    std::string getName() { return "Ugly"; }
};
#endif
```

#### NotAsUgly.hpp

```
#ifndef _UGLY_HPP_ // Same name as in Ugly.hpp---deliberately!
#define _UGLY_HPP_
struct Ugly { // Once again, duplicate name is deliberate
    std::string getName() { return "not as ugly"; } // All that DependsOnUgly depends on
};
#endif
```

Is there a special name for the type of fake object I'm using here? I'm inclined to call it a stub, but it is rather different than what I would normally think of as a stub. I would expect something called a *stub* to implement the interface of the class which is to be faked through inheritance. Here the implementation is only partial, and happens through the preprocessor.

Is there already a known name for this kind of fake/testing object? I want to name the header file that contains it (`NotAsUgly.hpp` in my example) to properly signify to other developers what it is for.

Comment: I posted about this technique, and a closely related one, [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16023540/834176).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has gone almost two months without anything but generic answers, so I judge that this is not a well-known pattern with an existing name. Therefore I suggest the name **Preprocessor Partial Mock**, to indicate that it is injected via a preprocessor seam and is only a partial implementation of the class being mocked.

Answer (score 2):

"[Mock Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)" is a common term.

Fake objects commonly provide a set of method stubs, returning pre-set values.

Mock objects commonly are richer in their behaviour, mimicking a more complete set of the real object behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the generic term "Fake" here.
On the other hand, "Stub" is also a good name. Your description of the fake class fits nicely with the definition of [stub on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stubs).